# Using regular expression in R to categorize data

Tags: regex, r, aggregate

I have a file with two columns, one has the content type of HTTP objects like text/html, application/rar etc and the other has the bytes size.

```
Content Type                                     Size
video/x-flv                                       100
image/jpeg                                        150
text/html                                         160
application/octet-stream                          200  
application/x-shockwave-flash                     ...
text/plain
application/x-javascript
text/xml
text/css
text/html; charset=utf-8
application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8           ...
```

As you can see there are many variations of the same content type, such as `application/x-javascript` and `application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8` and so on. So, I would like to create another column to categorize them more generically. So, that these two would just be `web/javascript` and so on.

```
 Content Type                                      Size      Category
    video/x-flv                                       100       web/video
    image/jpeg                                        150       web/image
    text/html                                         160       web/html
    application/octet-stream                          200       web/binary
    application/x-shockwave-flash                     ...       web/flash
    text/plain                                                  web/plaintext
    application/x-javascript                                    web/javascript
    video/x-msvideo                                             web/video
    text/xml                                                    web/xml
    text/css                                                    web/css
    text/html; charset=utf-8                                    web/html
    video/quicktime                                             web/video
    application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8                     web/javascript
```

How would I accomplish this in R and I presume I need to use regular expressions of some sort for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this one correctly... you want to use regexp to create 3rd column that consists of... what exactly? Could you be more precise, please?

Comment: well I will have more general categories that given in the content type field such as in the example video/x-flv, video/quicktime etc all come under one category "web/video" by searching for the text "video" in the column. Similarly, searching for "javascript" and putting it in "web/javascript" in the 3rd column. So, I figured searching for those keywords would need regexp.

Comment: I just need to know how I would do this searching and mapping the correspioding category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can simplify your variable. Here I will use the `stringr` package for string manipulation functions :

```
R> library(stringr)
```

First, copy your content type variable into a new character variable :

```
R> d <- data.frame(type=c("video/x-flv", "image/jpeg","video/x-msvideo", "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8", "application/x-javascript"))
R> d$type2 <- as.character(d$type)
```

Which just gives you :

```
                                     type                                   type2
1                             video/x-flv                             video/x-flv
2                              image/jpeg                              image/jpeg
3                         video/x-msvideo                         video/x-msvideo
4 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
5                application/x-javascript                application/x-javascript
```

Then you can work on your new variable. You can just replace manually certain type value by another :

```
R> d$type2[d$type2 == "video/x-flv"] <- "video"
R> d
                                     type                                   type2
1                             video/x-flv                                   video
2                              image/jpeg                              image/jpeg
3                         video/x-msvideo                         video/x-msvideo
4 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
5                application/x-javascript                application/x-javascript
```

You can use regexp matching to replace all the values matching, for example, "video" :

```
R> d$type2[str_detect(d$type2, ".*video.*")] <- "video"
R> d
                                     type                                   type2
1                             video/x-flv                                   video
2                              image/jpeg                              image/jpeg
3                         video/x-msvideo                                   video
4 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
5                application/x-javascript                application/x-javascript
```

Or you can use regexp replacement to clean certain values. For example by removing everything behind the ";" in your content types :

```
R> d$type2 <- str_replace(d$type2, ";.*$", "")
R> d
                                     type                    type2
1                             video/x-flv                    video
2                              image/jpeg               image/jpeg
3                         video/x-msvideo                    video
4 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 application/x-javascript
5                application/x-javascript application/x-javascript
```

Be careful of the order of your instructions, though, as your result highly depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had to do it by hand, you could assign your factors into corresponding categories. In this example, I group first 13 letters of the alphabet as "1" and the second half of the letters as "2".

```
> x <- as.factor(sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE))
> x
  [1] d n p n k l a x c n v p l o u e z m y x t r q b l n y s s m d u l l a d k
 [38] t a p x s g w i p l b s o t b s h h v c b j o p h f j m v d r m x o d l e
 [75] l f y l u e w f e e o s w s m v a z q l a t f z x s
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> levels(x)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
> levels(x) <- c(rep(1, 13), rep(2, 13))
> x
  [1] 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1
 [75] 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2
Levels: 1 2
> levels(x)
[1] "1" "2"
```

If your example contains (only) factors i.e.:

```
"video/x-flv" "image/jpeg" "video/x-msvideo" "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8"
```

... you would code your levels like so:

```
levels(obj) <- c("web/video", "web/image", "web/video", "web/javascript")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `DF` is our data frame.  Define a regular expression, `re` to match the strings of interest and then use `strapply` in the `gsubfn` package to extract them, prefixing `"web/"` to each.  In the `strapply` statement we have converted `DF[[1]]` to character just in case its a factor rather than a character vector. `NULL` entries were not matched so lets assume those are `"web/binary"` .  Finally expand any occurrences of `"plain"` to `"plaintext"` :

```
> library(gsubfn)
> re <- "(video|image|html|flash|plain|javascript|xml|css).*"
> short <- strapply(as.character(DF[[1]]), re, ~ paste("web", x, sep = "/"))
> DF$short <- sapply(short, function(x) if (is.null(x)) "web/binary" else x)
> DF$short <- sub("plain", "plaintext", DF$short)
> DF
                                   Content          short
1                              video/x-flv      web/video
2                               image/jpeg      web/image
3                                text/html       web/html
4                 application/octet-stream     web/binary
5            application/x-shockwave-flash      web/flash
6                               text/plain  web/plaintext
7                 application/x-javascript web/javascript
8                          video/x-msvideo      web/video
9                                 text/xml        web/xml
10                                text/css        web/css
11                text/html; charset=utf-8       web/html
12                         video/quicktime      web/video
13 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 web/javascript
```

There is more info on the `gsubfn` package at http://gsubfn.googlecode.com .